# how to display image in processing.js from PHP with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, processing.js

Hi i am trying to display image in processing.js sketch using jquery ajax request and php code but it is not showing image that i send to the sketch here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        //var s;
        function setPath(imgPath) {
            var s = imgPath;
            var processingInstance;
            processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('canvas');
            processingInstance.change(s);
        }
        var variable = 5;
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            tupe: "POST",
            url: "take.php",
            data: ({val: variable}),
            success: function (data) {
                setPath(data);
            },

        });


    }
</script>
```

This is my Processing code:

```
String pic; 
PImage img;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  background(150);
  img = loadImage(pic);
}

void draw(){

   image(img,50,50,width/2,height/2);  
}
void change(String val){
    pic = val;
    println(pic);

}
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    $temp = $_POST['val'];
    if ($temp == 5) {
        $img = "images.jpg";
        echo $img;
    }
}
?>
```

when i run code and print the result in the in the sketch i get the result of "images.jpg" but nothing is shown in the canvas someone know what to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `setup()` function is only called once, at the beginning of the sketch.

Your `pic` variable starts out with no value, and that's what you pass into the `loadImage()` function. You store the value returned (which is probably going to be a broken image) into your `img` variable.

Then in the `change()` function, you update the `pic` variable, but you don't update your `img` variable. Just because you change the `pic` variable doesn't mean that the image is magically reloaded for you. You have to specifically do that yourself.

It might look something like this:

```
void change(String val){
    pic = val;
    img = loadImage(pic);
}
```

In fact you could probably get rid of the `pic` variable completely.

Note that this also requires an image file located at the specified path.

Comment: Yeah, thank you i reed documentation again today and i saw it, i did just what you sugesting and it run now. I am not a programer yet, but i try to become some day and sorry for the stuped qestions but sometimes something little like `setup()` loading on start make me wandering all day, why the hell code does not runnig. Thanks again!

Comment: @MimiChan No problem. Your questions aren't stupid, and it sounds like you feel exactly how every programmer feels!